# How to use a proxy with RedditSharp?

Tags: c#, proxy, reddit

I'm using RedditSharp from https://github.com/SirCmpwn/RedditSharp in a script of mine, and I'm simply asking, when connecting using this how do I implement a proxy? and could I change the proxy midscript?

Comment: What type of proxy? Remote call proxy? Network proxy site? Mock objects? Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: I'm planning on probably using a SOCKS.

Answer (score 1):

There no standalone way, you can't accomplish this without modifying this library source code.

So most painless-way:

1. Overload constructor of RedditSharp - add new argument with IWebAgent as type. So it will look like this:

   ```
   public Reddit() : this(new WebAgent())
   {

   }

   public Reddit(IWebAgent agent)
   {
       JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
       JsonSerializerSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = false;
       JsonSerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
       _webAgent = agent;
       CaptchaSolver = new ConsoleCaptchaSolver();
   }
   ```
2. Remove "sealed" keyword from RedditSharp.WebAgent class declaration.
3. Make RedditSharp.WebAgent.CreateRequest method virtual, so it will look like this:

   ```
   public virtual HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method, bool prependDomain = true)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Create your own WebAgent based on old-one:

   ```
   public class MyAgent: WebAgent
   {
       public IWebProxy Proxy { get; set; }

       public override HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string method, bool prependDomain = true)
       {
           var base_request = base.CreateRequest(url, method, prependDomain);

           if (Proxy != null)
           {
               base_request.Proxy=Proxy;   
           }

           return base_request;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use it in your code:

   ```
   var agent = new MyAgent();
   var reddit = new Reddit(agent);

   ...

   agent.Proxy = new WebProxy("someproxy.net", 8080);
   ```

So now you can set proxy anytime, from anywhere. Not tested really, but it must work.

Comment: Thank you! However, I did this and it doesn't seem to be working for me. When I log in the login is successful regardless of what the proxy is, even if it's set to something that isn't a proper proxy IP and port. Is it detected as not real and is then ignored? How do I know if it's actually using the proxy, how can I test if the proxy is functioning or not before attempting to use it? and like I said, how do I make absolutely sure that it's actually using the proxy to log in?

Comment: After some experimentation, I'm pretty confident that the proxies I try to use are not working in the code and are being ignored. Because if I try to log in too many times with false passwords with a proxy, it still blocks me from logging in saying I must wait when I go to the website without a proxy in FireFox. I must've done something wrong.