# How could I use a Proxy with RedditSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, reddit

I just started to play around with RedditSharp (https://github.com/ddevault/RedditSharp) and I know I got a bit late to the party and I should be using OAuth instead, but I found it curious that this thing is still working by simply interacting with old.reddit.com.
My question is: is there any way I could connect to reddit using this library and a proxy?
I found this section ([How to use a proxy with RedditSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396205/how-to-use-a-proxy-with-redditsharp)), tried it but with no luck and couldn't find anything else besides that.
Thank you so much for the help.

I've tried the only solution found here: [How to use a proxy with RedditSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396205/how-to-use-a-proxy-with-redditsharp) but it seems is ignoring that I am using a proxy.

Comment: could you please mark the answer as accepted then?

Answer (score 0):

RedditSharp is a bit old ( 3 years old and un-maintained ). It seems [RedditSharp](https://github.com/ddevault/RedditSharp/blob/a5e1e6afb72966deccc298c8692bf47f04c039a2/RedditSharp/WebAgent.cs#L127) is using `WebRequest` to make `HTTP` requests. In this case, you can use [`DefaultWebProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy?view=netframework-4.8) property of `WebRequest` class.

> **WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy**
>
> The DefaultWebProxy property gets or sets the global proxy. The
>   DefaultWebProxy property determines the default proxy that all
>   WebRequest instances use if the request supports proxies and no proxy
>   is set explicitly using the Proxy property. Proxies are currently
>   supported by FtpWebRequest and HttpWebRequest.
>
> The DefaultWebProxy property reads proxy settings from the app.config
>   file. If there is no config file, the current user's Internet Explorer
>   (IE) proxy settings are used.
>
> If the DefaultWebProxy property is set to null, all subsequent
>   instances of the WebRequest class created by the Create or
>   CreateDefault methods do not have a proxy.

Example:

```
var proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxyObject;

// init RedditSharp stuff here
```

You can read more about `WebProxy` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: What I found it that ReditSharp is using HttpWebRequest and what I did, following on the answer above, was doing something like so:

var proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest.Proxy = proxyObject;

I will try with an unexistant proxy to check if I get a connection exception.